# Incrementing a date by the {point.x} value in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a series of sparkline charts using HighCharts.  The data is being defined in the data-sparkline attribute of the span.  Along with this, the data-sparkdate attribute of the span refers to the month of the first data point. Something like:

```
<span id="sparky" data-sparkdate="Sep-2015" data-sparkline="584.783333, 624.500000, 611.666666, 651.725806, 602.416666"></span>
```

When you hover over the spark line markers, the label shows you the current value, start month and the index number of the x point.  i.e. `Sep-2015, 1 612`, `Sep-2015, 2 625`, `Sep-2015, 3 612` and so on.

What I would like like to do is to add the x index to the date and show is as: `Sep-2015, 612`, `Oct-2015, 625`, `Nov-2015, 612` and so on.

As you can see on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbdkmvky/2/) I have tried to add `{point.x}` to the date value, but it doesn't get evaluated to a number.  Is there any other way to increment date by one at each marker?

thanks

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbdkmvky/2/)**

Comment: I would suggest using a *datetime* x axis type, and using the *pointStart* and *pointInterval* properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @jlbriggs comments I have used `pointStart` and `pointInterval` to achieve this without a formatter function. The API also has `pointIntervalUnit`.  If I set this to 'month' then the x-value gets incremented by a month from the start date automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formatter for xAxis labels and refer to the stringdate variable.

```
  xAxis:{
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels:{
        formatter: function() {
            return stringdate + ', ' + this.value;
        }
    }
  },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/3khfd1h6/